# Extracting data from multiple JSON objects

Tags: php, twitter, json

I want to extract the Tweets from sample Twitter data such as http://pastebin.com/AvHnxKpz

I've tried using the PHP function json_decode and then looping through to output the 'text' field but had no joy, especially when the input is several objects as it is in the sample data.

I can use `$json = json_decode($input, true);` and then `$json['text']` to extract the Tweet from a single entry, e.g.

```
{"created_at":"Sun Apr 28 17:31:15 +0000 2013","id":328562066359205888,"id_str":"328562066359205888","text":"RT @NameIsLauraa: I think it's cute when guys are ticklish \u263a"}
```

However when the input contains numerous entries such as

```
{"created_at":"Sun Apr 28 17:31:15 +0000 2013","id":328562066359205888,"id_str":"328562066359205888","text":"RT @NameIsLauraa: I think it's cute when guys are ticklish \u263a"}

{"created_at":"Sun Apr 28 17:31:15 +0000 2013","id":328562066329837568,"id_str":"328562066329837568","text":"RT @R_Piz23: Lupa lak nak post caramel pudding yg sedap aku buat dulu tu @Ainie_Kim ..terliur la kau kan.. nasib la badan..homemade aiskrim\u2026"}
```

The code does not work.

Comment: Please show your code, it's hard to guess. Also, what does "no joy" mean? Did you get an error message or something? Did you use `print_r` to see if the object got correctly converted?

Answer (score 0):

Your Twitter data seems to contain mixed JSON entries, some for **delete** actions and others for **created_at** actions.

I put up a sample code snippet for you to see how to get the `text` field from one of the **created_at** actions.

See it in http://codepad.org/N1VlteMc.

#### Update

> The body of a streaming API response consists of a series of newline-delimited messages, where "newline" is considered to be \r\n (in hex, 0x0D 0x0A) and "message" is a JSON encoded data structure or a blank line.

Basically you'll just have to parse message text for \r\n tokens. Read the following Twitter documentation pages to understand how to handle the stream:

- [Processing streaming data - Parsing responses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/processing#Parsing_responses);
- [Streaming message types](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/messages).

Comment: That was the part I had working. The problem is when the input contains several entries. I've edited my question with this info :)

Comment: Where are you getting that input from? What you've posted is not valid JSON :s